# Instrumental variable regression: How many interpretations?

Tags: econometrics, instrumental-variable

I was reading Amemiya ["Non-linear regression models"](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1573441283010107) (1983) in which he says that

> This statement should not be construed as a criticism of Theil's
> interpretation. I know of at least  six more interpretations of 2SLS:
> a certain interpretation works better than others when one tries to
> generalize 2SLS in a certain way. Thus, the more interpretations, the
> better.

Does anyone have any idea of what these 6 interpretations or at least just some of them may be?